# How to use an external backend with SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to use SvelteKit with an **external backend**.
Let's consider the backend is not in NodeJS, already done and running and that every bit of non-static data comes from it.

The goal is to use **SSR** and other great SvelteKit's features, while being able to handle *authenticated cookie*s, *xsrf tokens* and more on the backend.

I feel the way to go is by using an `adapter` that uses the external backend for SSR and forwards all requests.
I could not find such adapter already available neither officially or made by the community.

What is the easiest way to do the above ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. When you say you have an existing external backend, do you mean an API? Is it returning formatted pages or just data? What do you mean by 'uses the external backend for SSR'? Why do you want to forward requests?

Comment: An API that return only data and manages authentication and cookies.

Comment: "uses the external backend for SSR" -> all data used to render a page comes from this backend

Comment: Right, so why not use an off-the-shelf adapter? There's nothing out of the ordinary in your planned use. You will have to come up with actual, specific problems to get more detailed answers. Right now your question is a bit too broad/vague.

Comment: You can use a svelte kit endpoint to fetch data from the backend. You might want to read one of the blog posts or video tutorials explaining how to do this.